# Can i remotely power on IBM server with Remote Supervisor Adapter II

Tags: webserver, remote-control

I have seen that on server  `IBM x3850` there is `Remote Supervisor Adapter II`

I just want to know that can i turn on and off the server remotely with card or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can.

[This is the link](http://download.boulder.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/systems/support/system_x_pdf/43w7827.pdf) to the RSA II user guide (PDF)